# Android Automatically Update Notification Using Timer

Tags: android, timer, notifications

i want my activity to refresh then display notification based on refreshed values every 5 minutes. I already got a refresh button and it's working fine. but when i try to activate the refresh button before the notification appears in the timer. my app just crashes.

Here are my codes

//Oncreate

```
            if(ordercounter>0) //ordercounter is the updated value
            {

             MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();

                Timer myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(myTask, 1, 300000);
            }
```

//Timer

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {

        refresh.performClick(); // this line is the cause of error pls help
        generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "You have "+ ordercounter+ " pending orders!");
    }
}

private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, Admin.class), 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                .setContentText(message).build();

        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);




}
```

// My refresh button

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = getIntent();
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you show the error log?

Comment: Also, do you need this refresh to happen even if the app goes asleep? If so, you probably should use AlarmManager instead of TimerTask

Comment: yes i would like for it to do a refresh so that the next notification will be updated but i don't want it to re open while the app goes asleep.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use an AlarmManager and set it to be activated every 5 minutes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            millisecondsToFirstActivation,
            millisecondsForRepeatingSchedule, alarmIntent);
```

The you create a broadcast receiver that is going to display the notification

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        displayNotification();
    } 
}
```

you can find more info here:
http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: hello! i tried to put the first code on my on create then the second code after my oncreate but my app wont open for some reason